# Very large empty indented space in left margin of Pycharm editor in Distraction Free Mode?

Tags: pycharm

I am a long-term `PyCharm` veteran but have just seen a behavior new to me. There is a very large empty space on the left side of the editor:

[image]

What is that for and how can it be removed - e.g. an `Appearance` setting?

**Update** I discovered it is only happening in `Distraction Free Mode`.  Why is that indent added?